# eslint just show important errors in node express project

Tags: unit-testing, express, eslint

I have an Express 4 project for my backend. Normally in webstorm I use all the errors about spaces, colon, quotes, but they are not really erros. Until I've delete "transMsg()"  function from ../utils/communutils.js

I was surprise that my "node run" was executed normally with that silent error. Webstorm give a underline color like another common no  important errors, when when I move the mouse over ".transMsg;" I get a popup with the message 'Unresolved variable transMsg'

const t = require('./utils/commonutils').transMsg;

so I've decide to execute 
  npm run test

my package.json:

```
"test": "eslint . --ext .js --ext .jsx --ignore-path .gitignore --cache",
```

my .eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb"],
    "env": {
        "browser": false,
        "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": 0
    }
}
```

then i get 214927 errors !

how to do to ignore those trivial errors and get important erros like 'Unresolved variable transMsg'. I know i can set up every error to get silent or just warning, but the list is  very long, is there a way to do it?

In react front app, those trivial errors are hidden, but important errors abort the execution of program. In this case npm run , run silent...

Part of errors;

```
   8:3   error  Assignment to property of function parameter 'info'                          no-param-reassign
  10:2   error  Missing semicolon                                                            semi
  15:62  error  Missing trailing comma                                                       comma-dangle
  22:34  error  Unnecessarily quoted property 'context' found                                quote-props
  22:34  error  Strings must use singlequote                                                 quotes
  22:45  error  Strings must use singlequote                                                 quotes
  22:57  error  Unnecessarily quoted property 'metric' found                                 quote-props
  22:57  error  Strings must use singlequote                                                 quotes
  37:3   error  Newline required at end of file but not found                                eol-last

✖ 246991 problems (243461 errors, 3530 warnings)
  214927 errors, 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

Comment: First, eslint is not for unit testing. It does quite simple static analysis on AST mostly to enforce code style policy. So do not expect it to catch runtime errors. As of disabling "unimportant rules". You are extending airbnb config which is quite large and opinionated. Just start from scratch (remove `exteds: blahblah` line) and configure rules you consider to be "important".

Comment: I can't remove  airbnb, because when i type code on webstorm, help me to write better quality code, but i need separte eslint from webstorm from real test, maybe need another config for test for eslint?